# UWC is unable to convert the HTML tags to correct form in Confluence

Tags: mediawiki, confluence, universal

I am using the UWC to convert our Mediawiki data to Confluence. I am able to create text files for all the data successfully. But I figured out that some pages have HTML tags in the text files

eg - Title of Page

After checking throughly I found out that this is the way data is stored in the Mediawiki database. So it gets carried forward to the text files created.

When this text file is used to create pages in Confluence, it doesn't get converted to h1 or h2. Thus the page created in Confluence contains the data with the html tags in them.

So my question is, does the UWC support this type of syntax or do I need to write my own parser to parse such occurences of HTML tags.

Secondly, I have a problem with the bullet points as well. What I found is say there are 4 bullet points under a topic, say for 3 the style is maintained and the last is converted as "*". This occurs sometimes for some pages only.

eg-

In the text file

```
* Topic 1

* Topic 2

* Topic 3
```

In Confluence

- Topic 1
- Topic 2

.

```
 * Topic 3
```

Thirdly, the attachments are not getting carried to Confluence. I tried to search for the attachments location in Mediawiki but could not locate it.

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The UWC does its best with the data it receives. I'd suggest looking at the mediawiki properties file to tweak the html conversions and also look at any regex that you can use to more successfully cleanse your data.

UWC does work well, but think as it as the basis of the conversion that requires some carressing rather than a complete out of the box solution.